# TSQL query undefined

Tags: javascript, t-sql

I am working on a project, where I am utilizing the Google Maps API, to autocomplete the address for me.

API DOCS: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete

The response I am getting from the API is somewhat similar to this

```
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {long_name: '15', short_name: '15', types: Array(1)}
1: {long_name: 'Endrupvej', short_name: 'Endrupvej', types: Array(1)}
2: {long_name: 'Fredensborg', short_name: 'Fredensborg', types: Array(2)}
3: {long_name: 'Danmark', short_name: 'DK', types: Array(2)}
4: {long_name: '3480', short_name: '3480', types: Array(1)}
length: 5
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

The reason I am using this API is to make sure no mistakes is made when registrering on my website.

I am trying to get the 4th index in the object with following code.

```
document.getElementById("zip_code").value = place.address_components[4].long_name;
```

This works fine, the problem for me comes when I try to parse this into my SQL statement, as I get the following error

```
message: "Invalid column name 'undefined'.",
```

### My register user controller

```
const createUser = (req, res) => {
  sql.connect(config, function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);

    // create Request object
    var request = new sql.Request();
    let { name, surname, email, address, zip } = req.body;
    let id = uuidv4();
    let userPassword = req.body.password;
    let hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(userPassword, saltRounds);




    // query to the database and get the records
    request.query(
      `insert into users(User_ID, User_firstName, User_surname, User_email, User_password, User_address, User_zip) VALUES ('${id}','${name}','${surname}','${email}','${hashedPassword}','${address}',${zip})`,
      function (err, recordset) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log("User added to DB");
        }
      }
    );
  });
  res.redirect("/login");
};
```

### My HTML

```
<form action="/createUser" method="POST" class="py-5 col-6">
<input
type="text"
class="form-control"
id="zip_code"
name="zip"
placeholder="Adresse.."
required
disabled
/>
</form>
```

Hopefully somebody can help me figuring this out!

Comment: You're injecting raw zip code into your SQL statement and you didn't quote it, so it becomes a column name. You should be using prepared statements and placeholders.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález from what I understand you're saying I should use the statement as `insert into users(User_ID, User_firstName, User_surname, User_email, User_password, User_address, User_zip) VALUES ('${id}','${name}','${surname}','${email}','${hashedPassword}','${address}','${zip}')`,` When I do this i get following error `message: "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'undefined' to data type int.",` I have tried turning the zip into a Integer, but cannot figure out how.

Comment: I don't know what library you're using but syntax often looks like `INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2) VALUES (:col1, :col2)` or `INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?)` and you pass actual values in an array. That would solve the SQL injection error, `$zip` is still undefined.

Comment: Use `parseInt(zip)` to convert the value to an int, but definitely use parameterized values in order to avoid SQL injection

Comment: @squillman, Yes ofcourse always paramenterized values, this will be added as last thing. When I use parseInt(zip) i get following error `message: "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'NaN' to data type int.",` It seems like the value of the input field isnt parsed to the controller. What could be cause this?

Comment: Have you inspected `req.body`? Does it have a `zip` key with a value? Your HTML element has the `disabled` attribute.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thank you Álvaro, works if I remove the disabled attribute.